# NFS vs CIFS show two different sizes of used space

Tags: 16.04, mount, nfs, cifs

**EDIT:**  I have filed a bug against this one at https://bugzilla.samba.org/show_bug.cgi?id=13570

---

I have been using a CIFS mount for a while, but recently I have setup a NFS mount for testing.

When I get a `df -h` from the server side I get this mount in return:

```
/dev/md1p1       15T  7.4T  6.4T  54% /media/storage
```

So, I have mounted now the same share from the above host on the client in both CIFS and NFS, but I have ended up with 2 different sizes in used space

```
//10.0.0.220/storage        15T  8.1T  6.4T  57% /media/NAS
10.0.0.220:/media/storage   15T  7.4T  6.4T  54% /nfs/server
```

The CIFS mount shows 8.1TB used, but the NFS shows 7.4TB which matches the server itself.  Where would the CIFS overhead be coming from?

Comment: I have also voted to close due to this being a bug.