# Samba not transfering all files

Tags: samba, smb

I am using samba to share movies on my local network. The files are stored on ubuntu 20.04 and if I try to read them from my other PC (Windows 10 or LibreElec) it shows ony some files. The permission for all files are the same. I tried moving it to different folder and it didnt help. For example I am sharing one folder and inside it I have about 7 TV Shows, but through samba I can see only 5 of them.

Comment: This is just an observation from me about Samba.  Through the years I have actually found Samba to be unreliable even with file sharing, [space used](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058815/nfs-vs-cifs-show-two-different-sizes-of-used-space) (which I filed a bug on that still has not been addressed or fixed), etc.  For file sharing I have switched over to NFS and for movie/TV show server I went with Plex.  I very rarely use Samba anymore.

Comment: But I need the files to be accessed from LibreElec, which I think is not suitable with Plex.

Comment: Do you know if LibreElec can work with NFS since NFS is still file shareing?

Comment: Yes, it can work with NFS. I will try create new share with NFS.