# LTS 16.04.07 Server - Extremly slow speed over ethernet port, even in LAN

Tags: networking, server, ethernet, lan, nas

I'm running an ASRock B85MPro4 that includes Intel's I217-V Gigabit ethernet port. It's weirdly slow. I tried uploading 170GB onto it and it was estimated to take 8 1/2 hours. i can barely exceed 15 Megabytes per second. The HDD is a brand new Seagate Barracuda, 7200 RPM.

I tried pretty much everything. Including:

-Disabling IPv6

-Manually updating the e1000e driver

-Running iPerf tests locally and over the public adress (which weirdly enough performed just as good as on windows, but still only reaching 300 Megabits per second) Results (local, the upper being the server running on Windows and the lower one Ubuntu):

```
[  4] local 192.168.178.30 port 56908 connected to 192.168.178.45 port 5201
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth       Total Datagrams
[  4]   0.00-1.00   sec  37.7 MBytes   316 Mbits/sec  4820
[  4]   1.00-2.00   sec  37.9 MBytes   318 Mbits/sec  4856
[  4]   2.00-3.00   sec  38.3 MBytes   321 Mbits/sec  4906
[  4]   3.00-4.00   sec  37.9 MBytes   318 Mbits/sec  4854
[  4]   4.00-5.00   sec  37.9 MBytes   318 Mbits/sec  4847
[  4]   5.00-6.00   sec  37.9 MBytes   318 Mbits/sec  4852
[  4]   6.00-7.00   sec  38.4 MBytes   322 Mbits/sec  4914
[  4]   7.00-8.00   sec  38.4 MBytes   322 Mbits/sec  4909
[  4]   8.00-9.00   sec  38.0 MBytes   319 Mbits/sec  4866
[  4]   9.00-10.00  sec  37.7 MBytes   316 Mbits/sec  4821
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth       Jitter    Lost/Total Datagrams
[  4]   0.00-10.00  sec   380 MBytes   319 Mbits/sec  0.000 ms  0/0 (0%)
[  4] Sent 0 datagrams

iperf Done.

C:\Users\[REDACTED]\Documents\iperf-3.1.3-win64>iperf3.exe -c 192.168.178.45 -u -b 2000m
Connecting to host 192.168.178.45, port 5201
[  4] local 192.168.178.30 port 53139 connected to 192.168.178.45 port 5201
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth       Total Datagrams
[  4]   0.00-1.00   sec  35.8 MBytes   301 Mbits/sec  4588
[  4]   1.00-2.00   sec  35.0 MBytes   294 Mbits/sec  4481
[  4]   2.00-3.00   sec  34.7 MBytes   291 Mbits/sec  4446
[  4]   3.00-4.00   sec  35.0 MBytes   293 Mbits/sec  4483
[  4]   4.00-5.00   sec  25.6 MBytes   216 Mbits/sec  3280
[  4]   5.00-6.00   sec  20.8 MBytes   174 Mbits/sec  2664
[  4]   6.00-7.00   sec  28.8 MBytes   243 Mbits/sec  3692
[  4]   7.00-8.00   sec  21.9 MBytes   183 Mbits/sec  2798
[  4]   8.00-9.00   sec  20.8 MBytes   174 Mbits/sec  2657
[  4]   9.00-10.00  sec  19.5 MBytes   163 Mbits/sec  2493
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth       Jitter    Lost/Total Datagrams
[  4]   0.00-10.00  sec   278 MBytes   233 Mbits/sec  0.000 ms  0/0 (0%)
[  4] Sent 0 datagrams
```

-Running the same speedtest using `speedtest-cli` and speedtest.net on the windows parition i set up extra to verify the integrity of the port. I achieved 10 Mbits/s Download and 27 Mbits/s on Ubuntu compared to 300Mbits/Download and 27 Mbit/s upload on Windows. I also downloaded some large files in Windows, as Ookla was already accused of bias in favor of certain ISPs.

-I asked a friend from NJ to ping my server and pass the latency which was okay with around a 100ms. (I'm situated in Europe)

-I used other devices in our household to measure latency by pinging the server. Where i managed to get 141237ms with one device. Which is really not good to say the least.

-Some weird wordpress guide that suggested removing the resolv.conf and using network-manager to replace it. Which just busted my connection but i was able to reverse the change.

I could only imagine that i need to tweak some Samba settings, forcing it to use the entire bandwidth. But that would still not explain why the download-rate result with `speedtest-cli` is so low.

I'm stumped at this point, i was awake the entire night to wrap my head around this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance

Comment: I've seen this before but try powering off the server and remove it from power.  Then press the power button in for about 10-15 seconds.  Then plug it back in and power it back on.  Then test the speeds again.  Mine actually kept doing this over and over and the power reset would help each time.  Turned out on my system that I needed the r8168 driver from the card manufacturer instead of the 8169 driver that comes with Ubuntu.  Check with the actual chipset manufacturer if there is a better driver.  This is only a guess though.

Comment: Hm, i've unplugged it a few times but that is new to me. ASRock is really shitty with this. They only provide Downloads for Windows. And their suggested version number is 20.2. Which is extremly old. But i'm pretty sure it is the correct driver. Also interesting development, i moved on in the meantime and downloaded a larger file on Ubuntu and actually achieved 60MB/s. Maybe the ```speedtest-cli``` is faulty afterall. Your approach sadly didn't help, NAS speed still sucks.

Comment: "Ethernet Auto-negotiation"? See `https://www.speedguide.net/articles/ethernet-auto-sensing-and-auto-negotiation-2184` and  `https://www.speedguide.net/articles.php`. It's a long read, but worthwhile.

Comment: I actually considered that aswell! But couldn't imagine why it would matter.

Comment: So i've read the quick summary and i can safely say that both ports are set to full duplex and run on 1000 Mbits. I'm starting to really believe this is some Samba isolated issue

Comment: @GrossKahn Hmmm, Samba might be an issue.  I actually stopped using Samba and went to NFS for a bug that was driving me crazy!  Come to think about it, I really never got good speeds from Samba either.  I wrote this one up for the bug I mentioned:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058815/nfs-vs-cifs-show-two-different-sizes-of-used-space  However, iPerf doesn't rely on Samba for speed testing.  That is one that has me stumped here.