# Cannot open Libreoffice files from network

Tags: libreoffice, xfce, smb

I am using Ubuntu Studio 20.04 with xfce, I am having troubles to open Libreoffice files which are on my network server (Synology NAS), regardless which protokol I use (smb, afp).
Other applications seems to be working fine, just LibreOffice not. The opening app flashes on the screen and disapears.
libreoffice-gnome and gfvs-backends are installed

Anybody else has problems like this?

Richard

Comment: Ubuntu Studio 20.04.2

Comment: I am not quite sure, what you mean - this is what I get, if I type lsb_release -a

If that is an invalid release, that could explain, why it is not working. Question remains, what it is available to download...

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
Release: 20.04
Codename: focal

Comment: Nope, mine open just fine across my network.  I am using an NFS mount from my NAS system to my Ubuntu, but it works fine opening documents that way.  I use LibreOffice 7.1.3.2.

Comment: Hm, my installation came with LibreOffice 6.4.7

Comment: You can upgrade to the newest version through LibreOffice themselves.  `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/ppa` then Enter for the refresh of the new repo and all repos.  Then `sudo apt upgrade` should upgrade LibreOffice to 7.1.3.2

Comment: Thank you, but befor I upgrade I would like to find out, what is realy wrong, I am not convinced it is LibreOffice. On my other Mint installtion I have no problems.
How could I debug this - I see no messages in system log, ist there other place I can look? Or are there some debug paramater I need to turn on?

Comment: I would check your versions on both Ubuntu and Mint.  I would also check for snap vs non-snap installed versions of LibreOffice since snap apps are confined and tend not to like to read outside of their specifically assigned folders.  For me, I will only run very few snaps for that reason.  For example, I use Plex Media Server, but the snap version will not read past the `~` or home folder and none of my media is in the home folder.  The .deb version of Plex Media Server works fine.

Comment: I decided to upgrade and installed 7.1.3.2 - still cannot open any smb files. Must be something Ubuntu Studio does different as other Ubuntu installations?
Unfortunately debugging LibreOffice seems to be quite a task, I made a strace, but I do not see much in there. It is complaining about location being not mounted - I am not that good with networking but smb should be handelt as local I believe (I might be wrong).
I do not think my office is intalled with snap, it came with the whole Ubuntu Studio package, upgrade was made using apt.

Comment: Now I noticed I cannot open some .png files from the network server either (but some I can), must be also something with the way Ubuntu process netowrk files - maybe the temp-file name construction?

Comment: Ok, I installed another file manager - PC File Manager and it is working fine, seems to be also a problem in Thunar.
Has anybody an idea how to fix/setup Thunar to work properly?

Comment: I use Thunar and I am able to open up directly across my network without any issues in LibreOffice or any other app like that.  However, I don't use Samba (SMB) due to bugs in it, especially when it comes to space reporting.  I use NFS instead and have never had an issue with it and have never looked back either.  This is one of the bugs I filed:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058815/nfs-vs-cifs-show-two-different-sizes-of-used-space