# Mount CIFS doesn't work after reboot but will work from command line

Tags: mount, fstab, cifs

In /etc/fstab I have the following

```
//10.10.1.191/TVENALL /mnt/medias/tv/TVENALL cifs auto,defaults,nofail,vers=3.0,credentials=/etc/plex.cred,uid=master 0 0
```

In journalctl -b I see the following

```
Aug 14 13:50:03 hsplx181 kernel: CIFS VFS: \\10.10.1.191 Error -104 sending data on socket to server
Aug 14 13:50:03 hsplx181 kernel: FS-Cache: N-cookie d=000000003fdc3b12 n=00000000b7faa4cf Aug 14 13:50:03 hsplx181 kernel: FS-Cache: N-key=[8] '0200008b0a0a01c4' Aug 14 13:50:03 hsplx181 kernel: FS-Cache: Duplicate cookie detected Aug 14 13:50:03 hsplx181 kernel: CIFS VFS: \10.10.1.196 Error -104 sending data on socket to server Aug 14 13:50:03 hsplx181 kernel: CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -2 Aug 14 13:50:03 hsplx181 mount[1142]: mount error(2): No such file or directory
```

also this

```
Aug 14 13:50:03 hsplx181 systemd[1]: mnt-medias-tv-TVENALL.mount: Mount process exited, code=exited, status=32/n/a
Aug 14 13:50:03 hsplx181 systemd[1]: mnt-medias-tv-TVENALL.mount: Failed with result 'exit-code'. Aug 14 13:50:03 hsplx181 systemd[1]: Failed to mount /mnt/medias/tv/TVENALL.
Aug 14 14:07:19 hsplx181 kernel: CIFS VFS: parse_server_interfaces: malformed interface info
Aug 14 14:07:19 hsplx181 kernel: CIFS: Attempting to mount //10.10.1.191/TVENALL
```

But If I run sudo mount -av it works with any error.

Ubuntu Server 20.04.06 LTS

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: After you mount it manually, try running `cat /etc/mtab | grep 10.10.1.191` and you should see a line that you can copy and paste to your `/etc/fstab` file replacing the line you already have.

Comment: I already tried the noauto,x-systemd.automount without any success even the _netdev

But I'll try out the Terrance command suggestion to get the working mtab info

Thanks

Comment: Tried the /cat/etc/mtab no success...  Doesnt work at reboot

Comment: I revisited Waltinator comment I simplified my line

Before:
//10.10.1.191/TVENALL /mnt/medias/tv/TVENALL cifs auto,defaults,nofail,vers=3.0,credentials=/etc/plex.cred,uid=1000 0 0

After:
//10.10.1.191/TVENALL /mnt/medias/tv/TVENALL cifs credentials=/etc/plex.cred,_netdev,noauto,x-systemd.automount 0 0

It's working now! wasn,t before with the _netdev value.

Comment: Feel free to write up your own answer.  It can help others.  Make sure that you give as much details in your answer as you can so that others can follow if they bump into the same thing.

Comment: @Terrance I would... but don't see how I can do that! :)

Comment: Ah, I see that it got closed.  :(  Looks like the Community bot caught your comment and backed up the vote to close.  One thing that threw me off is that I forgot that I am using NFS4 and not CIFS because I don't like the bug I found where my 16TB mount gives me incorrect free space.  I ended up filing a bug on it.  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058815/nfs-vs-cifs-show-two-different-sizes-of-used-space

Comment: @Terrance thanks and I'll take a look at your post